# « Vous ou moi devrions » ou « Vous ou moi devrais »

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Dit-on :

> Vous ou moi devrions...

ou

> Vous ou moi devrais...

Ou ni l'un ni l'autre, dans le contexte :

> Vous ou moi [devoir] obtenir de plus amples informations sur cette problématique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La troisième personne n'est pas possible sans l'ajout de *on*:

> <s>Vous ou moi devrait obtenir</s>...
>
> Vous ou moi, **on** devrait obtenir...

La première personne est exclue, même avec l'ajout de *je*:

> <s>Vous ou moi devrais obtenir</s>...
>
> <s>Vous ou moi, je devrais obtenir</s>...

Les formes suivantes sont possibles:

> Vous ou moi, **nous** devrions obtenir... (la plus courante à l'écrit)
>
> Vous ou moi devrions obtenir...
>
> Vous ou moi devriez obtenir... (moins courant, suppose un ou exclusif)

et aussi:

> L'un ou l'autre d'entre nous devrait obtenir... (ou exclusif)
>
> L'un d'entre nous devrait obtenir...
>
> L'un de nous deux devrait obtenir...

Exemple :

> *Ce garçon-là, dit un de mes maîtres à un étranger qui visitait la pension, est en état de haranguer un auditoire en grec, mieux que vous ou moi ne pourrions le faire en anglais.* - *L'Anglais mangeur d'opium*, Thomas de Quincey, traduit de l'anglais et augmenté par Alfred de Musset, 1828.

Answer (score 3):

Non locuteur natif du français, je préférerais dire :

> L'un de nous devrait obtenir de plus amples informations sur cette problématique.

pour éviter toute sorte de hésitation possible.

En ce qui concerne la formulation en question je dirais :

> C'est moi ou vous qui devrais...(accord avec moi)

ou

> C'est moi ou vous qui devriez...(accord avec vous).

Voir [termiumplus.gc](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_o&page=9209NTKuNwxE.html).

Answer (score 0):

Le sujet n'est pas clairement défini dans la phrase. Aucune des phrases n'est claire.

- On devrait obtenir plus d'informations.
- Nous devrions obtenir plus d'informations.
- Vous devriez obtenir plus d'informations.
- ...